# Complicated condition in JOIN

Tags: mysql, sql

I have one table Products, and second Prices. One product can have mupltiple prices.

Important columns of Table Products

Id, Name

Important columns of Table Price

Availability, Price, SupplierId

I need JOIN Price which has Availability > 0 AND has lowest Price.

More details about performance:

- more than million products that means more prices
- index is on pri.ProductId but can be added to more

Also I need to be able to order these results by Name of product or by Price

Something like:

```
SELECT * FROM Products pro 
JOIN Prices pri ON pri.ProductId = pro.Id 
AND MIN(pri.Price) AND pri.Availability > 0
```

Comment: Do you mean to say the price is _less than_ that of the other table?  `LOWER()` is a MysQL string function to convert to lower case... http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_lower

Comment: lower prices that what?  LOWER converts a string to lowercase...

Comment: Sorry my mistake, now its edited as MIN()

Comment: For the avoidance of confusion, consider providing a sqlfiddle

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT * 
FROM Products pro 
JOIN 
(
  select ProductId, min(Price) as mprice, Availability
  from Prices
  where Availability > 0
  group by ProductId 
) pri on pri.ProductId = pro.Id
```

Comment: Does this select corresponded availability for price with lowest price ?

Anyway I have over milion of products and more than milion prices so this is very ineffective I think.

Comment: ..assuming there's only two kinds of availability

Comment: availability can be 0 but also 1,2,3,4 etc.

Comment: @PetrVelký: Please add all necessary info to your question. And since this is also a performance issue you should add table structure (with indexes), example data and expected output.